# Django admin - Mixing multiple model inlines in single admin interface

Tags: python, django, inheritance, django-admin

I have a Django model layout that looks something like this:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

class Publication(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)        

    #Some shared fields

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Book(Publication):
    #Book specific fields

class Poem(Publication):
    #Poem specific fields
```

Generally speaking, I'd like to show information listed by author and sorted by some information, like pub_date, so that the end user would see something like:

Author A:

- Poem 1
- Poem 2
- Book 1
- Poem 3
- Book 2

Author B:

- Book 1
- Book 2
- Poem 1
- Poem 2
- Book 3

And so on.  I can figure out how to display these on the front-end (I can either use django-polymorphic or simply combine the author.book_set.all() and author.poem_set.all() into a single list and sort).  But I CANNOT figure out how to implement this in the Admin site.  I would like the structure to be exactly the same as above -- so that when I click on Author A I'd get:

- inline for Poem 1
- inline for Poem 2
- inline for Book 1
- inline for Poem 3
- inline for Book 2

If I simply attach Poem and Book as TabularInlines, they would be separated out into separate fieldsets, like so:

- inline for Poem 1
- inline for Poem 2
- inline for Poem 3
- inline for Book 1
- inline for Book 2

But I think it's important for functionality that they are mixed together in a single fieldset (with the fields specific to the other child class either grayed out or not present for each inline).  Does anyone have any idea how to implement this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, it didn't seem like there was a simple way to do this, so I delved into django.contrib a bit and built an app for handling this: Django Merged Inlines.  If it would be useful to anyone, it's available here:

https://github.com/MattBroach/Django-Merged-Inlines